# Why do we need "canonical" well-orders?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, well-orders

*(I asked this question on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443117/why-do-we-need-canonical-well-orders)*

Von-Neumann ordinals can be thought of "canonical" well-orders, Indeed every well-order $W$ has a unique ordinal that is its "order type".

This raises the question of *why* a canonical order is needed, it seems to me that every application of ordinals can be done by using a "large enough" well-ordered set instead that is guarenteed by Hartog's lemma$^{1}$, for example, instead of performing a transfinite process on an ordinal, we perform it on the "large enough" well ordered set $X$ whose existence is guaranteed by Hartog's lemma. Using this method we can prove the first basic applications of ordinals such as Zorn's Lemma(See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4132884/789929)). This seems to beg the question, if there is a *deeper reason* for ordinals than mere **convenience**.

$\small{1}$: For the purposes of this question let Hartog's Lemma state: For every set $S$, there exists a well-ordered set $X$, such that there is no injection from $X\to S$.

Notes:

-- This is not an entirely useless question that does not "affect things" in any way, since ordinals $\ge \omega+\omega$ need not exist in $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Replacement}$, and indeed the above method gives a proof of Zorn's lemma in
$\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Replacement}$.

-- I suppose one can ask a similar question about cardinal *numbers*: Why do we need cardinal numbers, when we can reason about cardinalities using simply injections and bijections on sets?

-- I realise that this probably a very *näive* question for a set-theorist, but it is something whose answer seems to be hidden for the non set-theorist, which is why I ask this question.

—- Ordinals seem to give a "uniform definablity" but is that actually useful?

**Edit**: Probably I should clarify that I do realise that the above observations imply that ordinals can be avoided by the "working mathematician", but I am more interested in why they are so important to the working *set*-theorist/logician(given that they literally are a set-theorists "bread and butter").

And even if convenience is *the* answer why do we need a formal notion that takes hours to develop when an informal notion seems to suffice(formally)?

Comment: I guess even if we didn't have ordinal *numbers*, we'd want to talk about order *types* (in order to develop ordinal arithmetic, etc.), but order types are proper classes. Having a canonical representative from each class lets us model the order types as objects of first-order set theory.

Comment: But the class of all ordinals is not a set, and if we don't have canonical numbers, we would still have for each well-ordered set $(X,\preceq)$, a set of representatives of all well-orders below the given one, namely all sets of the form $\{y:y\prec x\}$ for $x\in X$ or is my thinking wrong here?  In other words, wouldn't we do it just the way we do it for ordinal numbers, pick one ordinal $\alpha$ large enough so we can carry out our calculations in $\alpha$ instead of the class of all ordinals?

Comment: If you want to build a model of number theory within set theory, you need rigorous definitions of the natural numbers, namely: the finite Von Neumann ordinals. The infinite Von Neumann ordinals come along for a free ride... and it's kind of a fun ride.

Comment: @fweth It can be done the same way, true. But your argument uses ordinals and replacment while mine does not.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think the point is that it’s not a free ride, since it requires assuming replacement.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku yes, I wasn't arguing agains your point, just answering to Karl that I don't think using ordinal numbers helps us with size issues (avoiding proper classes) since we must fix a large enough ordinal number / well-ordered set either way in order to carry out our computations, but I guess I was just repeating what you already wrote in the question.

Comment: The first interesting application of Order Types that I am aware of is in the construction of successor cardinals. Another application is in defining ordinal arithmetic. As to your question about cardinal numbers, they have many uses beyond measuring the size of objects. Such as with the Large Cardinal Axioms. - Which are part of a program of stengthening ZFC into a theory where many independence results are resolvable.

Comment: It's really not a naive question--for the vast majority of applications (certainly all applications in "ordinary mathematics"), you don't need ordinals, and they are primarily just a convenience.

Comment: The main way I can think of that ordinals might actually matter is that they give you a single *definable* well-ordered class in which all well-ordered sets embed.  This is extremely convenient when you want to think about the structure of the *entire* universe of sets as a whole, via things like the von Neumann hierarchy.  I'm not sure how truly necessary they are for this, though.

Comment: There are also some funny very technical ways in which the definition of the von Neumann ordinals is important because it is "simple"--in particular, it uses only bounded quantifiers.  This, for instance, has the not-at-all-obvious consequence that well-foundedness is *absolute* between transitive models of ZFC, essentially because well-foundedness is controlled by the ordinals and the well-foundedness of the ordinals is baked into the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @EricWofsey Interesting, why can’t one use the same Hartogs “trick” for the Von Neumann hierarchy? I really want an answer that explains the use of ordinals in set theory than general math, so an explanation of why definability is important for the set theorist would be helpful too!

Comment: @EricWofsey I think it would be nice if you would write an answer!

Comment: @EricWofsey The axiom of regularity is not required for the well-foundmess of ordinals. An (von Neumann) ordinal is (by definition) a transitive set strictly well-ordered by $∈$

Comment: @ℋolo: That definition is not absolute without the axiom of regularity, though.  The point is that regularity implies it suffices to assume they are *totally* ordered by $\in$, which is absolute between transitive models.

Comment: For some "syntactic" purposes, we want well-order-types to admit canonical representatives definable in a particularly simple way. But often these purposes are not of intrinsic interest to those "working logicians" who are not particularly committed to specific presentations of set theory (e.g. as structure $(V,\in)$ satisfying certain first-order axioms). Truth is, even the working logician can often get by without canonical well-order-types: this is what Leinster does in his [Large Sets](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2021/06/large_sets_1.html) series (Part 4 covers ordinals).

Comment: I would recommend looking at Kanamori's essay "In Praise of Replacement". According to the account there, Godel tried for several years to develop what became the constructible hierarchy without the Von Neumann ordinals before realizing they were essential to getting the idea to work.

Comment: @EricWofsey You managed to salvage the Hartogs argument, would you know a place where that does not work?

Comment: Maybe ultrapowers @EricWofsey ?

Comment: @EricWofsey What about constructing a set of size $\aleph_{\omega}$? I think one either needs ordinals or global choice for that...

Comment: @EricWofsey In retrospect my above comment is wrong since Hartogs lemma actually gives us a pretty explicit well order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convenience** is important, but let's ignore this point.

First let's talk about how easy it is to get ordinals: Say we start with $\sf ZF-Replacement$ and we want to have transfinite recursion, then the resulting theory is the full $\sf ZF$. (I apologize, but I don't remember if this result is by B. Rin or JDH) which means we get "all" of the ordinals again!

Interestingly enough, $\sf ZF(C)-Replacement+Recursion\ on\ Ord$ is strictly weaker than $\sf ZF(C)$, but usually we do out recursion on general sets.

Some reasons to want the axiom of replacement can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228168/what-does-the-axiom-of-replacement-mean-and-why-should-i-believe-it), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208711/who-needs-replacement-anyway), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550378/why-when-we-need-the-axiom-schema-of-replacement), I will assume replacement for the rest of the answer.

One big advantage of the ordinals, it is that they are a proper class that is well-ordered, in particular you can do stuff along all of the ordinals. Using
Hartog's lemma will only give you set-size applications.

For example: a class-size cumulative hierarchy, e.g. defining $V_α$ in [von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), or $L_α$ in the [Constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).

Those constructions are very important.

Another very important construction is [$\sf HOD$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set).

Apart from constructions, there are few important result concerning absoluteness, one example was given by Eric in the comments. Another (non-obvious) result is that: if $M,N$ are transitive models such that $M⊨\sf ZFC$ and $N\models\sf ZF$ such that $M,N$ has the same ordinals and the same *sets of ordinals*, then $M=N$. This result uses the following fact about ordinals: for every set $x$, there is a set of set of ordinals $A$ that encodes uniquely $\operatorname{trcl}(\{x\})$ that is definable only with $x$.

Some other surprising results that are in the same spirit as the previous paragraph, the following are equivalent in $\sf ZF$:

1. There exists a definable injection $F:V\to \mathcal P(Ord)$
2. There exists a definable function $F:V\to V$ such that if $|X|>1$ then $∅≠F(X)⊆X$
3. For every $x\ne y$ there exists an ordinal $α$ such that $(V_α,∈,x)\not\equiv(V_α,∈,y)$

Another application of ordinals (and the cumulative hierarchy) is that it gives as a way to measure height of stuff. The rank of a set $x$ is the first ordinal $α$ such that $x\in V_{α+1}$. An example it is useful is: if $M$ is a model of $\sf ZF$, and $N\prec M$ of height $β$, then $\{x\in M\mid M∃α∈N\;\models"α\text{ is an ordinal and the rank of $x$ is $<α$}"\}=V_β^M$ satisfy $N\preceq V_β^M\prec M$, such $β$ is a "correct cardinal", so an elementary submodel of the universe implies that there exists a transitive elementary submodel of the universe.

This is only touching the edge of the iceberg of the usefulness of a cumulative hierarchy.

---

A different point you had in your post is, why not just look at equivalence classes? The problem of this approach is that each equivalent class (apart from $0$) is a proper class, not a set.

The way to deal with this problem is something called [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick), which allow you to look at disjoint proper classes as a collection of disjoint sets.

In $\sf ZF$, without $\sf AC$, this is indeed how we define general cardinals. The problem is that we need for this trick some cumulative hierarchy that cover all of $V$, whose construction uses ordinals.

---

Indeed in all of the above, if you find some proper class $C$ that is well-ordered and set-like (every proper-initial segment is a set), then you can replace the ordinals with initial segments of $C$ and get basically the same results, but the problem is to find such $C$ without already using the ordinals.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144784/discussion-on-answer-by-olo-why-do-we-need-canonical-well-orders); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Holo: ok understood your last comment, but given that Eric Wofsey managed to salvage the Hartogs argument, it would be nice if there was an argument where the class $C$ is crucial, would you know of any such argument?

Comment: Is this comment section over?

Comment: @ℋolo What about constructing a set of size $\aleph_{\omega}$? I think one either needs ordinals or global choice for that... we can continue the discussion in chat if you want....

Comment: (If my above example works, you can add to your answer)